# Validation for date time fields in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have made a simple Google form with three fields.

1. Cabin (dropdown)
2. From (datetime)
3. To (datetime)

Before I hit the submit button, I need to validate two things

1. date time entered in "To" should be greater than "From"
2. time difference should be less than 16 hours

I have searched everywhere but could not find a setting to add this validation. I have searched google and StackOverflow posts for a similar query but could not find anything that matches my requirement.

I am attaching a screenshot of the google form and also the google form URL. Please help me on how to achieve this.

Google Form URL: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScI_Ixdrm4gPIl8O-Lb9_VrYbwq_uDPWHGKGsDKZk-5_BWfgA/viewform

[Google Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs3w3.png)

Comment: you want to datavalidate the form entry or output of the form?

Comment: thank you for your reply. i want to validate while user is entering data and if the condition does not match then throw an error message. if the datavalidation happens at entry level then the output will anyways be correct. I tried a lot to look for references but could not understand how to achieve this.

Comment: "In contrary to Short text, paragraph and checkbox questions, Google Forms doesn't have a way to validate input through date questions." @Ruben from [How to validate a date in Google Forms?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115812/196152)